# In the vis.js library, how do I get the max value in the "id" field?

Tags: dataset, vis.js, vis.js-network

I'm discovering vis.js, especially the network module.

I need to get the max value of the "id" field of my nodes dataset:

```
var nodes = new vis.DataSet([ {id: 1, label: "Node 1"}, {id: 2, label: "Node 2"}, {id: 3, label: "Node 3"}]);
```

The best I've been able to do so far is using a forEach loop:

```
var max=0;
nodes.forEach(function(el){j=parseInt(el.id);if(j!=NaN && j>max){max=j;}});
console.log("max: ", max);
```

It seems to me it can't be THE way to do this.
I saw a `max(field)` method documented in the doc for vis' DataSet (https://visjs.github.io/vis-data/data/dataset.html):

> max(field) [Object|null]  Find the item with maximum value of specified field. Returns null if no item is found.

But as stupid as i may sound, I just can't get it to work.
I tried :

```
console.log("max: ", nodes.max('id'));
console.log("max: ", nodes.max(node => node.id));
console.log("max: ", nodes.max(node => node['id']));
```

How can I simply get the max value of the field 'id' of all entries of a DataSet?

**[Edit]** The ID's in the example here above are numeric (`{id: 1, ...}`).
In my case, they were strings (`{id: '1', ...}`), and exactly that seemed to be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After loads of lost time, I finally figured out that max() works perfectly with numeric IDs.
My first thought was then: *Reading the doc could have saved me hours...*

...But checking https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/nodes.html , it explicitely defines ID as a string:

> [name:] **id**    [type:] **String**  [default:] **undefined**    [description:] **The id of the node. The id is mandatory for nodes and they have to be unique. This should obviously be set per node, not globally.**

So beware: it's supposed to be a string, but if it's a string, some features don't work.
If I'm still missing something, I'd be happy to read your comments.

Comment: I finally contributed some commits on github which have been merged into the doc: nodes.id is now defined as "number or string" (https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/nodes.html), and dataset.max() working only on numeric values is now also documented as such (https://visjs.github.io/vis-data/data/dataset.html#Methods)

Comment: Spot on! You saved me so much time! :)

Answer (score 0):

try this line:

```
nodes.max('id').id
```

nodes.max('id') will return the node with the max id value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately ``nodes.max('id')`` returns null, so ``nodes.max('id').id`` raises an error

Comment: Well... I just tried fiddling around on a fiddle example from vis network doc, there it works like a charm... https://jsfiddle.net/5k3jus28/   So I must have a bad config, or a bad option somewhere, or badly initialized anything... I simply can't figure out, what :-(

Comment: I finally got it. Due to DB data-storage, my indexes were rendered as strings ('1', '2'...) and passed as such to vis.DataSet. It seems that they have to be numeric in order for DataSet.max() to work properly.